# Cannot call Rails endpoint from NodeJS server (from within a Redis pmessage event)

Tags: node.js, http, post, redis, request

**Node Version:** *0.10.33*

I'm able to successfully use CURL to issue my POST request from the CLI and get a 201 response back, as well as use Postman in Chrome to get a successful 201 response back, but when I try to issue the POST request from NodeJS, using either the `http` module, or the `request` third party library, I get this error message from Node:

```
error:  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

And I don't get any logs at all from Rails (as if Rails isn't found by Node for some reason).

NodeJS code that I've tried: *(note that createPostData returns a JSON serializable object that becomes the post body)*

*In all examples, I made sure that railsHost was 'localhost' and railsPort was 3000.*

## First attempt:

```
redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
    var postData = createPostData(channel),
        options = {
            uri: 'http://' + config.railsHost + ':' + config.railsPort + '/resource',
            method: 'POST',
            json: postData
        };

    if (postData === null) {
        return;
    }

    winston.info('Creating request using options ' + JSON.stringify(options) + '\n and POST data ' + JSON.stringify(postData));

    request(options, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            winston.error(err);
            return;
        }
        var status = res ? res.statusCode : null;
        if (status === 201) {
            winston.info('Notification processed successfully by Rails');
        } else {
            winston.error('Rails could not create the Notification');
            winston.error('HTTP Status: ' + status + ' -> ' + (res ? res.statusMessage : 'response object was null'));
        }
    });
});

winston.log('subscribing to */*/queue1/pubsub');
redisClient.psubscribe('*/*/queue1/pubsub');

winston.log('log.txt', 'subscribing to */*/queue2/pubsub');
redisClient.psubscribe('*/*/queue2/pubsub');
```

## Second attempt

```
redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
    var postData = createPostData(channel),
        options = {
            uri: 'http://' + config.railsHost + ':' + config.railsPort + '/resource',
            method: 'POST',
            json: true,
            body: postData
        };

// ... the rest is the same as the First Attempt
```

## Third Attempt

```
redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
    var postData = createPostData(channel),
        options = {
            uri: 'http://' + config.railsHost + ':' + config.railsPort + '/resource',
            method: 'POST',
            // I also tried replacing 'body' below with 'formData' and 'postData'
            body: JSON.stringify(postData),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
                // I also messed around with upper-casing the 'c' and 't' in 'content-type'
            }
        };

// ... the rest is the same as the First Attempt
```

## Fourth Attempt - Now Using the HTTP Module Provided Natively by NodeJS

```
redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
    var postData = JSON.stringify(createPostData(channel)),
        options = {
            host: config.railsHost,
            port: config.railsPort,
            path: '/resource',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

    if (postData === null) {
        return;
    }

    winston.info('Creating request using options ' + JSON.stringify(options) + '\n and POST data ' + postData);

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        var status = res ? res.statusCode : null;
        if (status === 201) {
            winston.info('Notification processed successfully by Rails');
        } else {
            winston.error('Rails could not create the Notification');
            winston.error('HTTP Status: ' + status + ' -> ' + (res ? res.statusMessage : 'response object was null'));
        }
    });

    req.on('error', function (err) {
        winston.error(err);
    }

    req.write(postData)
    req.end();
});

winston.log('subscribing to */*/queue1/pubsub');
redisClient.psubscribe('*/*/queue1/pubsub');

winston.log('log.txt', 'subscribing to */*/queue2/pubsub');
redisClient.psubscribe('*/*/queue2/pubsub');
```

## CURL Command that Works

the test.json file contains the same json that the winston logs say I'm sending through the NodeJS request - copy-pasted from the terminal.

```
curl -d @test.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/resource
```

Got back a 201 response.

## Postman Request that Works

Same JSON as in the above CURL command - I just copy-pasted the Winston printout from the terminal that my code from the above examples prints.

URL: http://localhost:3000/resource
Request Type: POST
Headers: key = Content-Type  value = application/json
For the body, chose 'raw' and 'JSON' and then just pasted in my JSON that I copied from the terminal log statements.

got back a 201 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out an application I was using had mapped localhost to ::1 (IPv6), so Rails preferred that on startup and, thus, was not available on 127.0.0.1. It appears that Node was translating localhost to 127.0.0.1, thus the connection refused errors.

Running Rails on 127.0.0.1 using the -b option resolved my issue. I'll rely on Google to help me fix localhost on my machine k will probably involve some trivial changes to the hosts file)